# SVN freezes without any information in OS X

Tags: svn, osx-elcapitan, freeze

- OS:  El Capitan 10.11.6
- SVN: 1.9.2 (r1703836)

While trying to fire any of SVN commands the terminal always freezes with just 3-5 lines of SVN output. For example, if we run:

```
svn checkout svn://some-host.com/repo
```

then we can see just the following output and execution can not be interrupted even with `Ctrl+C` command:

```
A    repo/test.txt
A    repo/android
A    repo/android/gradle.properties
A    repo/android/gradlew.bat
```

The usage of another version of the SVN (reinstallation to the 1.9.4) gives the same result. And while this operation is being frozen in the terminal we can find some SVN process in the running processes list (using `top`) in the sleeping state:

```
3394  svn          0.0  00:00.05 2     0    39    2828K  0B     0B   3394 3123 sleeping *0[1]          0.00000 0.00000    501  2443
```

It's difficult even to find some clues of the described behavior. Also, the host of the repo (administrator) can checkout it on his machine, so it becomes completely confusing, why SVN on my machine has begun to freeze on all operations. Any suggestions?

Comment: And just for the record: you are sure that SVN isn't busy receiving one super large file and just appears to be frozen?

Comment: I don't see any processes using `ps -ef | grep svn`. How can I check this otherwise? 

UPD: Ah, understood you. It's possible, but I don't have any super large files in repo. The total size of the repo is about 50 MB, and it contains only small files.

Comment: For example by monitoring your file space? By doing a "find" in the directory where your checkout is going to? By *knowing* what you got within your repository?

Comment: The total size of the repo is 59 MB. All files are relatively small.

Comment: Then you can probably forget about that idea.

Comment: Ok, just another information. I've found another external repo, the size of which is more then 100 MB - I could download it in the couple of seconds. Now I think that SVN works correctly, but it's a kind of firewall or network blocking connection error...

Comment: `svn log` works correctly with my repo

Comment: I think that I could localize the problem. It's a kind of corrupted repo or there is some firewall on one of possible sides. I think so, because I can checkout other repos, and this corrupted repo I couldn't download even on another machine using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Then you probably simply want to delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a complete solution for symptoms described above.

I've got this idea after running svn connection from the completely different machine with the same network. My provider was blocking connection to the remote svn server - and this looks like as it was described in the question and comments for it. So, to avoid this behavior I have just set up a proxy and now everything works correctly!